# ¿como puedo buscar contenido en diferentes hojas de excel? c# datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

ando realizando un buscador de un excel importado a datagridview pero, me di cuenta que no puedo realizar búsqueda en hojas distintas ya que los campos de están no están, inmediatamente al hacerlo el programa me tira un error

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[TRANSFERENCIA/CHEQUE] LIKE '{0}%'" +
             "OR [RUT Beneficiario] LIKE '{0}%' " +
             "OR [Nombre Beneficiario] LIKE '{0}%'" +
             "OR [Monto $] LIKE '{0}%' " +
             "OR [Cuenta Destino] LIKE '{0}%'" +
             "OR [Banco Destino] LIKE '{0}%' " +
             "OR [N. acciones] LIKE '{0}%' " +
             "OR [Cantidad de Acciones] LIKE '{0}%' " +
             "OR Nombres LIKE '{0}%' " +
             "OR Apellidos LIKE '{0}%' ", textBox1.Text);
```

este código funciona pero solo si la hoja de excel posee los nombre de columnas puesto en otro caso el programa señala un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] este error sucede por tratar de buscar en otra hoja de excel donde no esta la columna

por esto tampoco e incluido con OR los nombre de las las otras columnas ya que no reconocería la hoja en la que ya están los nombre, daría el mismo error

por eso pregunto si existe una forma de buscar en otras hojas sin comprometer al buscado ya funcional, en el mismo textbox

codigo de importacion del excel

```
 using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    IExcelDataReader reader;
                    if (ofd.FilterIndex == 1)
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
                    else
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
                    reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                    result = reader.AsDataSet();
                    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                    reader.Close();

                }

            }
```

eso en un boton

Comment: Como estas recuperando los datos de excel?

Comment: los importo con exceldatareader, agregare al codigo

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres realizar un filtro dinamico, con las hojas de excel que vayas haciendo, deberias tambien generar los nombres de columnas dinamicos.

Paso 1: Leer las cabeceras de excel (los nombres de las columnas)

Paso 2: Generar un string con el filtro que vas a usar en el rowFilter.

Paso 3:

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format(STRING
  GENERADO)
```

Al momento de hacer el string vas a tener que ir concatenando por ejemplo:

```
string Filtro = "";
List<String> listaColumnas = new List<String>();
//Aca vas a tener que agregar todas las columnas que leiste con un foreach o como te 
quede comodo
//Aca recorres toda la lista y vas generando el filtro
foreach(string item in listaColumnas){
   Filtro += "OR [" + item + "] LIKE '{0}%'";
}
```

Comment: con agregar las columnas, son todas las columnas de todas las hojas verdad? es decir son 4 hojas, y como la agrego de que forma con el código que poseía yo para su búsqueda?

Comment: No, solo de la hoja que estas poniendo en el datagrid, la libreria que estas usando debe tener algun metodo para leer solo los nombres de las columnas

Comment: si fuera por leer y buscar en una hoja eso ya puedo hacerlo, pero el excel tiene 4 hojas, y queria ver si se podria buscar en todas sin tener conflicto con las otras hojas

Comment: Si queres buscar en las 4 hojas, primero deberias leer las 4 hojas y poner los datos en el datagridview

Comment: ya lee las 4 hojas carga el excel el programa, y el combobox sirve para navegar en las hojas, al seleccionar una, la carga automaticamente en el datagridview